# can GenericFutureListener.operationComplete be executed by a non-IO thread in netty

Tags: java, netty

From [ChannelFutureListener](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelFutureListener.html) docs:

> GenericFutureListener.operationComplete(Future) is directly called by
>   an I/O thread

I read netty 4.1.22.Final source code. It seems GenericFutureListener.operationComplete could be executed in the thread(**non-IO thread**) calling addListeners() 
while the event has finished but the listener hasn't been called.

```
// source code of DefaultPromise#addListeners() 
@Override
public Promise<V> addListeners(GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>>... listeners) {
    checkNotNull(listeners, "listeners");

    synchronized (this) {
        for (GenericFutureListener<? extends Future<? super V>> listener : listeners) {
            if (listener == null) {
                break;
            }
            addListener0(listener);
        }
    }

    if (isDone()) {
        notifyListeners(); // if called
    }

    return this;
}


// source code of DefaultPromise#notifyListeners() 
private void notifyListeners() {
    EventExecutor executor = executor();
    if (executor.inEventLoop()) {
        final InternalThreadLocalMap threadLocals = InternalThreadLocalMap.get();
        final int stackDepth = threadLocals.futureListenerStackDepth();
        if (stackDepth < MAX_LISTENER_STACK_DEPTH) {
            threadLocals.setFutureListenerStackDepth(stackDepth + 1);
            try {
                notifyListenersNow(); // if called
            } finally {
                threadLocals.setFutureListenerStackDepth(stackDepth);
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    safeExecute(executor, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            notifyListenersNow();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will always executed by the `EventExecutor` that was used to create the `DefaultPromise`. An `EventLoop` is a subtype of `EventExecutor` and most of the times used to create such an `DefaultPromise`.